# What is the default whois server for the whois command?

Tags: whois

What is the default whois server queried when using the `whois` command?

I use a `/etc/whois.conf` file to manage servers queried for the `whois` command. The contents of the file are based on [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/769448/218411). If I use the server listed in the answer for .com (`whois.verisign-grs.com`), all queries to domains registered with GoDaddy return an incomplete record.

However, if I comment out the entry in the file for .com, then the full whois record for a GoDaddy registered domain will be returned.

So I want to figure out what server is being queried when `whois` is using the default lookup settings.

Comment: can you explain little bit ?

Comment: @Raja I have provided some additional background on my question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `strace` which is a debugging tool to find what was really used:

```
strace --trace=sendmmsg --verbose=all -s 64 -o whois.strace.log whois google.com
```

`whois.strace.log`

```
sendmmsg(3, [{msg_hdr={msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\305\300\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\5whois\fverisign-grs\3com\0\0\1\0\1\0\0)\4\260\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=51}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, msg_len=51}, {msg_hdr={msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\375\304\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\5whois\fverisign-grs\3com\0\0\34\0\1\0\0)\4\260\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=51}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, msg_len=51}], 2, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
sendmmsg(3, [{msg_hdr={msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="8\333\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\5whois\vmarkmonitor\3com\0\0\1\0\1\0\0)\4\260\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=50}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, msg_len=50}, {msg_hdr={msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\f\336\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\5whois\vmarkmonitor\3com\0\0\34\0\1\0\0)\4\260\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=50}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, msg_len=50}], 2, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: `whois --verbose` also shows the used server

Answer (score 0):

When pulling up the man page on whois it has the follow description:

> DESCRIPTION
>          whois searches for an object in a RFC 3912 database.
>
> This  version  of  the  whois  client  tries  to  guess  the  right
>   server  to ask for the specified object. If no guess can be made it
>   will connect to whois.networksolutions.com for NIC handles or
>   whois.arin.net for IPv4 addresses and network names.

Comment: In reading [RFC 3912](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3912), it is not clear to me that a specific server is being queried. It seems like it is describing how to query a server.

Comment: Also, see my above comment to @muru to querying the stated dabases. The result is the same with both `whois.networksolutions.com` and `whois.arin.net` for .com domains.

Answer (score 0):

From [`man whois`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/whois.1.html):

```
   This version of the whois client tries to guess the right server to ask
   for the specified object. If no guess can be made it  will  connect  to
   whois.networksolutions.com  for  NIC handles or whois.arin.net for IPv4
   addresses and network names.
```

And:

```
   If the /etc/whois.conf configuration file exists, it will be  consulted
   to  find  a  server  before applying the normal rules. Each line of the
   file should contain a regular expression  to  be  matched  against  the
   query  text and the whois server to use, separated by white space.  IDN
   domains must use the ACE format.

   …

   WHOIS_SERVER
          This  server  will  be queried if the program cannot guess where
          some kind of objects are located. If the variable does not exist
          then whois.arin.net will be queried.
```

So, depending on `/etc/whois.conf` and `WHOIS_SERVER`:

- whois.networksolutions.com for NIC handles
- whois.arin.net for IPv4 addresses and network names.

Comment: If I put into my `whois.conf` file `\.com$ whois.networksolutions.com`, all `whois` queries for .com domains will return `No match for "EXAMPLE.COM".`

Comment: of course.. networksolutions is for NIC handles(a person or role object with a matching nic-hdl attribute).. example.com is a network name and that's arin.net

Comment: https://www.apnic.net/apnic-info/whois_search/using-whois/guide/role and https://www.apnic.net/apnic-info/whois_search/using-whois/guide/person documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your request your local whois client is contacting the central registry ( IANA ) and asking for the responsible domain registrar. The client is following the hierarchical references down to the registrar which can you provide the desired information. Source: https://whois.icann.org/en/dns-and-whois-how-it-works

Comment: However, if you were to use one of the newer TLDs, such as `.guru`, all `whois` queries for the TLD will return `No whois server is known for this kind of object.` So I don't follow how this explanation can be correct for how the `whois` command functions.

Comment: Just tried it with a random .guru domain and it worked - even without user-defined whois.conf . I created whois.conf with  ` \.guru$ whois.donuts.co` as content and it works also.

Comment: You are likely using a newer version of Ubuntu than I am (12.04). Just swap `.guru` for some newer TLD, and I suspect you will get the same response, as there are generally no changes made to that package once the version is released.